# multiplicacion y acumulacion de varios numeros ingresados por teclado

Tags: java

necesito si me pueden ayudar con lo siguiente necesito multiplicar todos aquellos numeros que sean menores a 0, ingresandolo por teclado, e ir acumulando las multiplicaciones.

Gracias

```
package control6;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Control6 {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
    int sumaPositivos = 0;
    int multi = 0;
    int contarcero = 0;
    int acumulacionmulti = 0;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;
        do {
            System.out.println("Ingresa un numero, cuando quieras terminar escribe 99999: ");
            n= sc.nextInt();
            if(n==0){
                System.out.println("El numero "+n+" es Cero");
                contarcero++;
            } else{
                if(n>0 && n!= 99999){
                    System.out.println("El numero "+n+" es positivo");
                    sumaPositivos = sumaPositivos + n;
                }else{
                    if(n<0 && n!= 99999){
                    System.out.println("El numero "+n+" es negativo");
                    multi = n*=n;
                   acumulacionmulti = multi++;

                    }    
                }
            } 
        }while(n != 99999);

        System.out.println("la suma de los numeros positivos introducidos es:  "+sumaPositivos);
        System.out.println("la acumulacion multiplicada de los numeros negativos introducidos es:  "+multi);
        System.out.println("la cantidad de ceros ingresados es:  "+contarcero);
    }
}
```

ese es el codigo que estoy haciendo

Comment: puedes por favor agregar lo que lleves avanzado?

Comment: dale en editar a tu pregunta y añade lo que lleves ahi

Comment: Enseñame como añadir todo el codigo que no puedo...porfavor soy nuevo

Comment: listo amigo, espero su AYUDA :)

Comment: muchas gracias por sus respuestas, y gracias a eso he resuelto el programa y la parte que me faltaba agradecido...que esten bien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo en mi caso, para ir **acumulando o guardando** lo que nos van dando la multiplicación de los números negativos, lo haría de esta manera.. `multi *= n;` que equivale a esto otro `multi = multi * n;`.

Pero haciendo esto tendríamos un *problema*, y es que el **primer valor de multi es igual 0**, y si vamos **multiplicando cualquier número por 0**, nos daría como **resultado 0**. Por lo tanto lo que haría es poner una condición que en caso de que se cumpla la condición de que el número ingresado es negativo y el valor de multi es 0, en vez de multiplicarlo, sería igualarlo al valor del número introducido, y ya a raíz de esto las siguientes veces que introduzcamos valores negativos ya sí, ir multiplicándolo por el valor guardado.

```
if (n < 0 && n != 99999) {
     System.out.println("El numero " + n + " es negativo");
     if (multi == 0) {
        multi = n;
     } else {
        multi *= n;
     }
}
```

---

Otra forma como bien ha comentado *@Zeugirdor*, es **inicializar** la variable **multi** con un valor de **1**, y cuando se ingrese un valor negativo directamente hacer la multiplicación y acumulación.

```
int multi = 1;
...
if (n < 0 && n != 99999) {
    System.out.println("El numero " + n + " es negativo");
    multi *= n;
}
```

Comment: Es innecesario, directamente declaras a m = 1 y si m es 1 al final del recorrido, no se incresó ningún número negativo, caso opuesto, hago m = m * n y listo

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia. Pero como lo tiene **inicializado a 0**, pues así se lo he expuesto. Y así ve donde tiene el fallo.

Answer (score 0):

Después de sus ayudas, he dejado el código de esta manera.
Muchas gracias.

```
package control6;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Control6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sumaPositivos = 0;
        int contarceros = 0;
        int acumulacionmulti = 1;
        Scanner Teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;
        do {
            System.out.println("Ingresa un numero, cuando quieras terminar escribe 99999: ");
            n = Teclado.nextInt();
            if (n == 0) {
                System.out.println("El numero ingresado " + n + " es Cero");
                contarceros++;
            } else {
                if (n > 0 && n != 99999) {
                    System.out.println("El numero ingresado " + n + " es positivo");
                    sumaPositivos = sumaPositivos + n;
                } else {
                    if (n < 0 && n != 99999) {
                        System.out.println("El numero ingresado " + n + " es negativo");
                        acumulacionmulti *= n;

                    }
                }
            }
        } while (n != 99999);

        System.out.println("la suma de los numeros positivos introducidos es:  " + sumaPositivos);
        System.out.println("la acumulacion multiplicada de los numeros negativos introducidos es:  " + acumulacionmulti);
        System.out.println("la cantidad de ceros ingresados es:  " + contarceros);
    }
}
```